# How do I enable 3 finger swipe down for App Expose in El Capitan

Tags: macos, mission-control

I have two machines side by side and cannot get the new one to mimic the app expose behavior.

- 10.10.3 Yosemite - 3 finger down will show all windows in the current app
- 10.11.3 El Capitan - 3 finger down does nothing

I want to keep the "Group windows by application" in Mission Control behavior.  I just want 3 fingers down to behave like Yosemite, any help would be awesome.

Answer (score 1):

System Preferences -> Trackpad -> More Gestures -> App Expose

And one thing changed since 10.10: From 10.11 it is 
4 fingers
instead of
3 fingers

It will never work with 3 fingers again, get used to it as a 4 finger gesture.

Comment: Ahh it's in gestures, awesome it works!